# QGIS QImage, can't specify a specific path

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, image

I'm a newbie in QGIS and I have to write a small python script to automate shapefile loading, applying style and save image. I'm having trouble on this last item.

Here is the thing:

> ```
> img.save("render.png","png")
> True
> img.save("C:\FOLDER\USER\render.jpg","JPG")
> False
> ```

Where `img` is a `QImage` instance. And I can't find the image produced with the relative path.

For a better understanding, here is all the code part concerning image output, which is from QGIS workbook :

```
img = PyQt4.QtGui.QImage(PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

color = QColor(255, 25, 255) img.fill(color.rgb())

p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

render = QgsMapRenderer()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
lst = [layer.id()]
render.setLayerSet(lst)

rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1) render.setExtent(rect)

render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

render.render(p)

p.end()

img.save("render.png","png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using backslashes, you need to use double backslash to escape the path. In my case:

```
img.save("render.png","png")
True
img.save("C:\Users\ME\Folder\\render.jpg","JPG")
True
```

Or you could use single **forward slashes**:

```
img.save("C:/Users/ME/Folder/render.jpg","JPG")
True
```